# How to get faster data from database

Tags: php, database

I'm a beginner php developer. I have a big database. I have been using postgresql database. For example a table has 10 gb data in the database. When I run 5 lines  a query I get response an average of 40 seconds. How can I get data faster. Which technologies should I use. Please help.

Comment: Without seeing table schemas, queries and explains, there's not much to say, make sure your indicies are right? If you're asking this though, I wonder where all the data came from.

Comment: have a look at this http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql-performance.html . Share schema or query where you want some optimization.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to consider if the design of your database is the proper one. Sometime if the design is not the correct you may have problems with the time of response. Also, in the querys try to get only the field that you will use. Don´t bring all the fields of the table.